# Editable Dropdown UX approach for iOS

Tags: ios, dropdown, drop-down-list

We have an input in an iOS app that needs to allow for any value but we would also like to suggest some options.

The number of options will be small, from 2 - 6 with 90% of the possible option lists being only 2 or 3 long.

I could use an ActionSheet or a Picker but those normally popup on tap of the input field so would prevent a keyboard being used to input "any value".

I'm currently thinking of using a TableViewCell with EditText and a Disclousre Indicator that would drop down an inline spinner.

This is an example of how we are proposing to display the options in Android. In this example there are 5 options and of course the option for the user to edit the text to whatever they want

[image]

If there was only one option we would simply default the edit box and not bother wasting the space with an option "list"

Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Comment: Have you got a wireframe of your current thinking?

Comment: No but I have screenshots of how we think we'll do it in Android and iOS

Comment: @PatLong-MunkiiYebee, try creating a wireframe using online tools like **[Moqups](https://moqups.com/)**. They have iOS UI components pre-defined in them. You wouldn't be stuck if you build mockups and wireframes.

Comment: @VarunKN I'm fairly certain that won't help as my issue is that this UX is non-standard so the won't have predefined components

Comment: Could you put an icon / text next to the input that pulls up a UIPickerView? 'Suggestions' in your action colour, then pop in on from the bottom?